# error: ‘Object’ does not name a type - trying to learn NodeJS N-API

Tags: node.js, c++11, n-api

Having trouble finding a sufficiently precise answer, basically my compiler `(GCC std=c++11)` does recognise the type "Object".

Yes, I am fairly new to ++

Tried changing command line options, tried Googling for an exact solution.

If anyone spots any other potential issues, please do let me know. I am finding the NodeJS docs a bit ambiguous in some areas.

I have included my code and command line output.

**Command line snippet:**

```
g++ exampleMod.c -I/usr/include/c++/4.8.5 -I/lhome/psyjw21/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64/include/node -I /usr/include/c++/4.8.5/x86_64-redhat-linux -std=c++11



    exampleMod.c:7:1: error: ‘Object’ does not name a type

    Object obj = Object::New(env);
```

**The code:**

```
   #define NAPI_VERSION 3
   #include <node.h>
   #include <node_buffer.h>
   #include <node_version.h>
   #include <node_object_wrap.h>

   Object obj = Object::New(env);
   obj["foo"] = String::New(env, "bar");
```

Comment: Also asking this question because whilst I expect if I really tried hard I could find a solution, I think there is fair potential of been told generally important info I need to know as a result of asking this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I have found the problem.

I included what was meant to be part of the Javascript in my C++ file.

obj["foo"] - I kind of realised what I did when I saw I had used a string as an array index... that isn't going to work in C++! (actually, I need to check a few things because I didn't think you could do it Javascript either).

Anyway, yes, feel free to comment on what a dumb mistake this was....